# Prepare statement for mysqli - num_rows gives 1 but get_result() gives nothing

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to use prepare statement(first time) for my login form. I am getting num_row as 1 but I am not getting anything with get_result(). Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
 public function login($username, $password) {
    $db = new DB();
    $conn = $db->connect();
    $encPass = md5($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$encPass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $row_count = $stmt->num_rows;
    echo "Number of rows: ".$row_count."<br>";
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
    if(!$result){
        die("error in receiving data ".$stmt->error." Error no. - ". $stmt->errno);
    }
    if($row_count == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION["user"] = serialize(new User($result->fetch_assoc()));
        $_SESSION["login_time"] = time();
        $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

Number of rows: 1

error in receiving data Error no. - 0

Comment: Do you have the `MYSQLND` driver?

Comment: I am not sure. I am using localhost - WampServer Version 2.5. But when I do this $mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
} 

It gives me 'mysqlnd enabled!'

Comment: `phpinfo()` will show everything you have loaded.

Comment: But it's more likely the problem in the linked question.

Comment: Yes When I tried phpinfo() . It looks like it is enabled

Comment: What do you mean when you say "problem in the linked question"

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate of another question. Follow the link to that question, it explains how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have look at it now. Thank you